# how to filter data from related table (Parse)

Tags: ios, parse-platform

Hiii guys i have to tables, first is "User" table and second is "PaidChatroom" table here is the structure

[image: This is a user table]

[image: this is a PaidChatroom table]

This the code i used for nearest user and it is working fine.

```
PFGeoPoint *userGeoPoint=[PFGeoPoint geoPointWithLatitude:currentLocation.coordinate.latitude longitude:locationManager.location.coordinate.longitude];


PFQuery *query = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"_User"];  
[query whereKey:@"location" nearGeoPoint:userGeoPoint withinKilometers:5000.0];
arrAllUser=[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];


[query findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray *objects, NSError *error) {
    arrAllUser=[objects mutableCopy];


}];
```

i want only those user who is nearest to me and purchased the dating, how can i filter the data.

Comment: You can perform nested queries

Answer (score 0):

```
PFGeoPoint *userGeoPoint=[PFGeoPoint geoPointWithLatitude:currentLocation.coordinate.latitude longitude:locationManager.location.coordinate.longitude];


PFQuery *query = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"_User"];  
[query whereKey:@"location" nearGeoPoint:userGeoPoint withinKilometers:5000.0];
arrAllUser=[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];

[query findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray *objects, NSError *error)
{
    arrAllUser=[objects mutableCopy];

    // Perform your second query here on the objects received inside this block for Purchased dating
}];
```